# Resolve duplication error in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am programming an android app with android studio . I also add some jars . I am trying to run it but I am getting this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files
> >     copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE

What should I do to solve it?

> Error:(32, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'packagingOptions()'
>   Possible causes:
>
> - The project 'xxxxxx' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method. Open Gradle wrapper file
> - The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin. Apply Gradle plugin

That's what I'm seeing, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try to add these line in your app gradle.

```
packagingOptions 
{
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
```

Comment: Should be perfect answer

Comment: Error:(32, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'packagingOptions()' Possible causes:

The project 'xxxxxx' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method. Open Gradle wrapper file
The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin. Apply Gradle plugin
thats what i m seeing now help

Comment: can you please post your build.gradle??